# SQL: How Do you Declare multiple paramaters as one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, declare

```
I am attempting to do the following


 1. Link two tables via a join on the same database
 2. Take a column that exists in both FK_APPLICATIONID(with a slight difference, 
    where one = +1 of the other I.e. Column 1 =1375 and column 2 = 1376
 3. In one of the tables exist a reference number (QREF1234) and the other
       contains 11 phonenumbers
 4. I want to be able to enter the Reference number, and it returns all 11
       phonenumbers as a single declarable value.
 5. use "Select * from TableD where phonenum in (@Declared variable)
```

Here is what I have so far,

```
Use Database 1

DECLARE @Result INT;

SELECT @Result = D.PhoneNum1, 

FROM Table1 

JOIN  TABLE2 D on D.FK_ApplicationID= D.FK_ApplicationID

where TABLE1.FK_ApplicationID = D.FK_ApplicationID + 1 
and QREF = 'Q045569/2'
Use Database2

Select * from Table3 where PhoneNum = '@result'
```

I apologise to the people below who didn't understand what I was trying to achieve, and I hope this clears it up.

Thanks

Comment: Your line `JOIN  DB1.Table2 D on D.FK_ApplicationID= D.FK_ApplicationID` is wrong. Both sides of the join are the same.

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all.  It uses aliases such as `db1` that are not defined and non-sensical comparisons such as `D.FK_ApplicationID = D.FK_ApplicationID`.  Fix your query.  Also, add sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why don't you just reference the tables in one query? the syntax would be something like Select * from MyDB1.dbo.TableA where PhoneNumber1 in (Select PhoneNumber1 from MyDB2.dbo.TableB)

Comment: So your table structure has fields `Phonenum1`, `Phonenum2`, `Phonenum3`, ..., `Phonenum11` and you want to match a phone number with any one of those fields?

Comment: I don't understand your end goal statement at all.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: Can this question now be closed since you got your answer here?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966404/sql-how-to-make-multiple-values-use-the-same-declare-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options but the best answer depends on what you are really trying to achieve.

There is a SQL trick whereby you can concatenate values into a variable, for example;

```
create table dbo.t (i int, s varchar(10))
insert dbo.t values (1, 'one')
insert dbo.t values (2, 'two')
insert dbo.t values (3, 'three')
go

declare @s varchar(255)

select @s = isnull(@s + ', ', '') + s from t order by i
select @s

set @s = null
select @s = isnull(@s + ', ', '') + s from t order by i desc
select @s
```

Alternatively, if you just want one value then you can use the TOP keyword, for example;

```
select top 1 @s = s from t order by i 
select @s

select top 1 @s = s from t order by i desc
select @s
```

Alternatively, you can use three-part-naming and just join across the databases, something like;

```
SELECT T.*
FROM   DB1.dbo.Table1
       JOIN DB1.dbo.Table2 D
         ON D.FK_ApplicationID = D.FK_ApplicationID
       JOIN DB2.dbo.Table T
         ON T.PhoneNum = RIGHT(D.PhoneNum1, 11)
WHERE  DB1.dbo.FK_ApplicationID = D.dbo.FK_ApplicationID + 1
       AND Hidden = 'VALUE'
```

Hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: To be honest, I am at a loss, I don't understand how this helps me, I apologise.

Comment: @Denslat - have you tried to run my third example? You will need to change the object names to reflect what they really are but it should give you what you want. If it does not work, why not?