# SQL How to make multiple values use the same Declare Variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, declare

I am attempting to do the following

1. Link two tables via a join on the same database
2. Take a column that exists in both FK_APPLICATIONID(with a slight difference, 
       where one = +1 of the other I.e. Column 1 =1375 and column 2 = 1376
3. In one of the tables exist a reference number (QREF1234) and the other
          contains 11 phonenumbers
4. I want to be able to enter the Reference number, and it returns all 11
          phonenumbers as a single declarable value.
5. use `Select * from TableD where phonenum in (@Declared variable)`

Here is what I have so far,

```
Use Database 1

DECLARE @Result INT;

SELECT @Result = D.PhoneNum1,phonenum2,phonenum3,etc 

FROM Table1 

JOIN  TABLE2 D on D.FK_ApplicationID= D.FK_ApplicationID

where TABLE1.FK_ApplicationID = D.FK_ApplicationID + 1 
and QREF = 'Q045569/2'
Use Database2

Select * from Table3 where PhoneNum = '@result'
```

The names of things like TABLE1 is not their true name

Thanks

Comment: What's the question? What are you stuck on?

Comment: what is the datatype of `D.PhoneNum1`,PhoneNum2,..` etc

Comment: D.phonenum is a field and a phonenumber

Comment: Why use a variable at all?   Why not include all three tables in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after something like this.
You are trying to "normalize" un-normalized columns and search for all those values in another table.
You need to union the results together into a temp table, then search for the values.

```
Use Database 1


Create Table #tmp(PhoneNums varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT D.PhoneNum1
FROM Table1 
JOIN  TABLE2 D on D.FK_ApplicationID= D.FK_ApplicationID
where TABLE1.FK_ApplicationID = D.FK_ApplicationID + 1 
and QREF = 'Q045569/2'
union
SELECT D.PhoneNum2
FROM Table1 
JOIN  TABLE2 D on D.FK_ApplicationID= D.FK_ApplicationID
where TABLE1.FK_ApplicationID = D.FK_ApplicationID + 1 
and QREF = 'Q045569/2'
union
SELECT D.PhoneNum3
FROM Table1 
JOIN  TABLE2 D on D.FK_ApplicationID= D.FK_ApplicationID
where TABLE1.FK_ApplicationID = D.FK_ApplicationID + 1 
and QREF = 'Q045569/2'

--Use Database2
--you don't need to switch databases if you use a fully qualified name like shown below.
Select * from Database2..Table3 where PhoneNum in 
(
   Select PhoneNums from #tmp
)
```

Comment: You magnificent son of a stackoverflow, it worked!

Comment: it did work... but I cant run it more than once... as the #tmp table already exists...

Comment: nevermind, I added a delete from #tmp at the top and it works now.and I only needed to create the table once.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a variable to hold multiple values and use the `IN` keyword.  You can pass a delimited list of values in, parse that, and then use `IN` with the collection of values you parsed.

In the code sample you posted, you can instead create a table variable, and select from that.

Comment: and how would I do that sorry?

Comment: @Jeremy's answer is what I was going for with the `table variable` comment.  He's just using a temp table instead.

Answer (score 0):

A variable can only hold a single value. Instead of using the `in` operator, you could accompish this same thing with a join...

```
Use Database1

SELECT distinct
    T3.*
FROM 
    Table1 
    JOIN  TABLE2 D on D.FK_ApplicationID= D.FK_ApplicationID
    JOIN Database2.dbo.Table3 T3 on
        T3.PhoneNum = D.PhoneNum1
        or T3.PhoneNum = D.PhoneNum2
        or T3.PhoneNum = D.PhoneNum3
where 
    TABLE1.FK_ApplicationID = D.FK_ApplicationID + 1 
    and QREF = 'Q045569/2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to type a bunch of ORs on a join you could use IN for your join.

```
select *
from Table3 t
left join Table2 D on t.PhoneNum in 
    (
        d.phonenum1
        , d.phonenum2
        , d.phonenum3
        , d.phonenum4
        , d.phonenum5
        , d.phonenum6
        , d.phonenum7
        , d.phonenum8
        , d.phonenum9
        , d.phonenum10
        , d.phonenum11
    )
    AND D.QREF = 'Q045569/2'
```

I would recommend instead that you normalize your data and then this isn't such a kludge.